# How to make multiple level sections in UITableView in Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

How to make nested table (multiple level sections) in swift 4 like the below picture:
[image]

A UITableView is designed to show just two levels (sections and rows), but I want to display more than two levels.

Comment: Go through this -> http://me.deepakbhati.com/2016/03/23/multilevel-uitableview/ and this -> https://github.com/amratab/ThreeLevelAccordian

Comment: @dahiya_boy this is an accordion view, I don't want an accordion tableview

Comment: Post some code . What u have done ,,? with that we will try

Comment: https://github.com/deepakbhati99/multiLevelUITableView this is perfect.

Comment: My answer is ok???

Answer (score 1):

Basic Section and Row.

```
var titleString = [0 : "Bat and Ball", 1 : "Hockey"]
var rowString = [0: ["Baseball", "Softball", "Cricket"], 1: ["Field Hockey", "Ice Hockey", "Roller Hockey"]]


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (rowString[section]?.count)!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SOTableViewCell
    cell.testLbl.text = rowString[indexPath.section]?[indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

// Uncomment for Default design and comment viewForHeaderInSection method
//func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    //return titleString[section]
//}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    sectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta

    let sectionName = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    sectionName.text = titleString[section]
    sectionName.textColor = UIColor.white
    sectionName.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    sectionName.textAlignment = .left

    sectionView.addSubview(sectionName)
    return sectionView
}
```